# Bug in Storyboards?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I'm trying to follow a YouTube tutorial on using constraints, etc and it gets you to set up a basic Storyboard along with some different coloured views. I can set them up fine, and put the widths, and heights in but as soon as I try to resize a view by the resizing arrows that appear around it's edge, all the other views disappear because their widths/heights are reset to zero. Am I causing this or is it a bug?

[image]

Comment: it is bug with xcode5

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. So you have to set all sizes manually?

Comment: I believe Xcode updates the views frame according to the constraints which you don't have, either add constraints at IB or disable auto-layout.

Comment: just restarting xcode can solve problem some time. it was happening with me too,OS X 10.10 and xcode5, but on OS X 10.9.4 it' never happened.

Comment: when it makes all otherviews reset frame or do something odd do Command+z undo it. and then add the same view but this time be careful while adding

Comment: I also just noticed that if I set the "Intrinsic size" to placeholder it doesn't reset the sizes.

Comment: Seems to be fixed at 6.1.1.